# Ruby : get value between parenthesis (without those parenthesis)

Tags: ruby, regex, parentheses

I have strings like `"untitled"`, `"untitled(1)"` or `"untitled(2)"`.

I want to get the last integer value between parenthesis when if there is. So far I tried a lot of regex, the ones making sense to me (I am new to regex) look like this:

- `number= string[/\([0-9]+\)/]`
- `number= string[/\(([0-9]+)\)/]`

but it still returns me the value with the parenthesis.

If there are no left-then-right parenthesis, getting an empty string (or `nil`) would be nice. Case such as `"untitled($)"`, getting the `'$'` char or `nil` or an empty string would do the trick. For `"untitled(3) animal(4)"`, I want to get `4`.

I have been looking a lot of topics about how to do that and but it never seems to work ... what am I missing here ?

Comment: Is the string `"untitled"` important or is is a stand-in for any string (e.g., `"cat(9)"`)? You have not defined "value". Must it be the string representation of a a non-negative integer (natural number), as in your examples, or a possibly-negative integer (which)? What do you want returned if the string were `"untitled"`, `"the cat in the hat"`, `"untitled($)"`, or `"untitled(3) animal(4)"`? Please edit your question rather than try to elaborate in comments (which should also stem further downvoting). Precision with words is as important as precision in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/(?<=\()\w+(?=\)$)/` matches one or more word characters (letter, number, underscore) within parenthesis, right before the end of line:

```
words = %w[
    untitled
    untitled(1)
    untitled(2)
    untitled(foo)
    unti(tle)d
]
p words.map { |word| word[/(?<=\()\w+(?=\)$)/] }
# => [nil, "1", "2", "foo", nil]
```

Comment: I think it's reasonable to assume that the parentheses may surround the string representation of a number (in view of the example) or an arbitrary string that does not contain a right paren (e.g., `"($)"`), but I see no basis for limiting the string to word characters.

Comment: Thanks ! it is working indeed, I will look at the doc to understand exactly why

Answer (score 0):

When you use Regex as the parameter to [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), you can optionally pass in the index of captured group to extract that group.

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

```
string = "untitled(1)"
number = string[/\(([0-9]+)\)/, 1]
puts number
#=> 1
```